# Xaml designer throws exception when the project code runs behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

When i try to load the view i.e., MainWindow.xaml, unhandled exception occurs. This happens only if the project code is running behind. Otherwise it works fine. Please help.Below are the exception details.

Screenshot here: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SCCF.jpg)

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: remoteValues
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalNotifyingEnumerable`2..ctor(IRemoteNotifyingEnumerable`1 remoteValues, Func`2 converter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerView.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerView.get_RelatedDocumentPaths()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)

I tried clicking on 'click here to disable the project code and reload the designer' . It works when i do this. But when i enable the project code, the same exception comes.

Mainwindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="QCFilterSaver.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroStyle}"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:QCFilterSaver.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="QC Filter Saver" Height="520" Width="1200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/MetroDark.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/MetroDark.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Controls\DataGridStyleDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MainDataTemplates.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Controls/Styles/LoadingArcsRing.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Controls/Styles/LoadingThreeDots.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <view:FSView x:Name="FSView" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


FSView.xaml:

<UserControl x:Class="QCFilterSaver.View.FSView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QCFilterSaver.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="520" d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:FSViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>  
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#a70711"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>  
    <Grid>
<!--my properties and bindings here-->
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The designer should load automatically without exception but it just does not.

Comment: According this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7330/an-unhandled-exception-has-occurred-with-xaml-desi.html) it should be fixed in visual studio 2017 15.0

Comment: Bug is still there in latest VS Version